# trouble with startup after power failure

Tags: boot, power

The last few times the power went out I have had trouble restarting.  The monitor shows entering power save mode.  I then hold the start button in to cold boot.  After the flashing amber light goes on the start button I restart.  After about twenty tries the machine comes up.  Does this mean my power supply is about to go?

Comment: Does anything happen prior to the 20 attempts? meaning, does it power down right away? Fans spin and stay on but no signal to your screen? If you could post some details in your question, it may add some clues as to what to look at. :)